# ElasticSearch - using several processes to index/add documents to speed up the indexing speed

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have an ElasticSearch index with huge size, 100 GB. Now indexing/adding documents to this index is slow.

I searched the solutions. Some people suggested that one approach is using multiple processes to index/add documents.

But I think the bottleneck is at ElasticSearch server side in this use case, multiple processes would add extra load to ElasticSearch.

I am not seeing too much improvement in indexing speed. On the contrary, I saw the processes reported errors such as "elasticsearch connection errors" and the processes are terminated.

But if I only have one process of indexing/adding documents running, I saw much less ElasticSearch errors reported.

When index size is small. I do use multiple processes to add/index documents, and it works great.

But when index size is huge, and indexing become much slower, and now I really need an approach to speed the indexing speed up. But it seems using multiple processes are not working in this use case when speeding up indexing is more needed.

Am I correct? Are there anyways or extra tuning I can do so that I can still use multiple indexing/adding document processes to speed up the indexing in this use case?

Thanks!

Comment: improve index performance:  1. using SSD  2. batch index (such 2k per request)  3. set refresh_interval as -1 and refresh manual .  On my test case three nodes can accept 20000-30000  index per second.

Comment: hope this might help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Comment: What is your elasticsearch cluster setup? How many nodes, shards, types of the nodes, etc.